# Не выделяется память под двумерный массив в С++

Tags: c++, массивы, borland-c++

Вот проблемный фрагмент кода:

```
double **Vz_alt;
if (!(Vz_alt=(double**)calloc(Nl, sizeof(double*))))  
 EmergencyExit ("GravEff_Alt (): memory for array 'Vz[Nl]' wasn't allocated\n");

for(int k=0;k<Nl;k++)
 if (!(Vz_alt[k]=(double*)calloc(Nx, sizeof(double))))
  EmergencyExit ("GravEff_Alt (): memory for array 'Vz[Nl][Nx]' wasn't allocated\n");
```

Переменные типа int Nl и Nx не пустые, содержат целые числа. Похоже, что в коде нет проблем, т.к. компилятор не выдаёт ошибок (использую Borland C++ Builder 6), однако память под массив не выделяется. С чем это может быть связано? И как эту проблему можно решить не прибегая к использованию статического выделения памяти под массив?

Comment: а как Вы узнаете, что память "не выделяется"?

Comment: Если бы память выделилась, то переменная Vz_alt имела бы значение отличное от NULL. Если это не так, то вызывается функция обработки ошибок EmergencyExit (), выводящая на экран текст описания ошибки. Последнее и происходит. 
И если выполнять программу по шагам, проверяя значения переменной, то её как было равно NULL, так и осталось.

Comment: я думаю, это может произойти, если `Nx` очень большое и у Вашего компа не хватает памяти (или просто нет такого куска памяти - память сильно фрагментирована). или `Nx` меньше или равно 0.

Comment: прошу извинить меня за не знание общепринятой терминологии. Поправьте  меня, если не прав: как-будто этой переменной функция calloc должна присваивать адрес первой свободной ячейки памяти из последовательного набора ячеек. Количество ячеек определяется переменной Nl. А затем, в каждой такой ячейке присваивается адрес первой свободной ячейки набора ячеек в количестве Nx штук.

Comment: И обе переменные Nl и Nx отличны от нуля. Nl<10, Nx<<100. Как-будто бы не очень-то и большие размеры.

Comment: @Garret, для начала просто распечатайте значения `Nl` и `Nx`

    printf ("Nl = %d Nx = %d\n", Nl, Nx);

Что Вы **видите** на экране?

Comment: Nl=2, Nx=50

Comment: @Garret Проверьте [`errno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) после того, как `calloc` вернул вам `NULL`. Очень сомневаюсь, что это происходит из-за нехватки памяти — скорее всего у вас dirty-write в каком либо другом месте кода, который затирает внутренние данные аллокатора. Включите полную отладку, runtime проверки выхода за пределы зааллокированых блоков памяти и используйте какой-нибудь [аналог CrtDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.90).aspx) для вашей среды. Если ваш код кроссплатформенный, то запустите [valgrind.](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @Garret Чтобы убедиться в этом, можете выцепить ваш текущий фрагмент кода в отдельное приложение — при разумных значениях `Nl / Nx` `EmergencyExit` у вас не произойдет никогда.